# Python script execute with system then serial.write() send data over serial and crash - Raspberry Pi and Arduino

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, pyserial

I have script which reading txt file (only numbers inside) and this script starting with system (before Raspbian Gui start). Everything's work fine, I can send text in byte:

```
def send_serial_stop(self):
       self.serialport.write(b'stop')
```

When I try to run this action - reading txt file and send data over serial, my script crash.
When I start script in Raspbian, everything works fine, and script not crashing. What's wrong with this code? I cannot read any errors because this app is in fullscreen mode. Have some tips?
Please help me, because I should finish this project until end of this week :(

```
def send_serial(self):
        file = open('testprog.txt').read()
        self.serialport.write(file.encode())
```

**EDIT**
When I use button with connected code (example above), script is terminated, and GUI application is closing.
Application is based on PyQt5 framework and GUI also.
Tere are around 150 lines of code in total.
Txt file has 24 characters (only numbers)
If I trying to run this script in Pycharm, everything works fine, when I start from terminal, situation is the same as during startup.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please explain what you mean by 'crashing'.  How large is this file?  What's the content of the file?

Comment: Hello ewong, today I added more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably problem is that you use relative path when opening text file.

Change it to absolute path:

```
file = open('/absolute/path/to/your/file/testprog.txt').read()
```

Comment: I fix this issue in GUI, but problem is still occur - my script running before Raspbian is completely run. And I see my script cannot load any other files except this python scripts...